# How do I avoid the error event in fine uploader when there is no response content on a successful upload?

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, fine-uploader

I've configured FineUploader to use CORS and work with my Amazon Web Services S3 bucket.

The problem I face, is that a successful upload does not return any response content (Status code 204 though, but the response content is empty). So even though the upload happens (I've verified the file is uploaded), the error event is triggered. Presumably, this is because there is no response.

How do I handle this case? Is there a way for me to manually trigger a 'success' by catching this error in the 'onError' callback?

**Edit:**

I've made some progress digging here. The error seems to stem from `handler.xhr.js`.

In particular, inside the `parseResponse(xhr)` function.

```
try{
   response = qq.parseJson(xhr.responseText);
}
catch(error) {
   log('Error when attempting to parse xhr response text (' + error + ')', 'error');
   response = {};
}
```

This seems to throw an error since the response is empty.

Does anyone know what a proper response should be? I'm thinking of adding a line here checking for an empty response and then manually plugging in what a correct response should be.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? I just looked in the source code and jQuery has a special case for `204` status codes, but it looks like it should fire `success`

Comment: I'm using jQuery 1.9.1

Comment: The version of jQuery is not relevant here as the requests are not sent or handled by jQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was with the `parseResponse()` function after all. It expects successful uploads to return the JSON string `{"success": true}` after a successful upload.

In my case, Amazon returns an empty response with a 204 status code. The 204 status code [implies no response is needed](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).

I've fixed this in my case by modifying the section mentioned in my edit as follows:

```
try {
            if(xhr.status == 204 && xhr.responseText.length == 0){
                response = qq.parseJson('{"success": true}');
            }
            else{
                response = qq.parseJson(xhr.responseText);
            }
}
```

Hopefully this will help others who run into this issue in the future.

Comment: Your comment on the expectations of Fine Uploader is correct for upload POST requests.  Fine Uploader is currently capable of sending a couple different types of requests.  One type, upload POST requests, require a valid JSON response, as described in the documentation.  This is especially critical for non-File-API browsers (IE9 and older) that use a form inside a hidden iframe to upload the file.  In those cases, there is no way to determine the response code client-side.  Work is planned to natively support direct uploads to S3 in the very near future.  Please see http://bit.ly/Z5J4Iz.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. It's a fantastic plugin to use. Fortunately for me right now, it's also pretty simple to debug in situations like this.

Comment: Hi Nikhil , I am running through the same problem. Do let me know where you have put this try code. In the callbacks section or somewhere else ??